# Assign IP address by phsyical USB port

Tags: usb, ethernet, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi with two HUAWEI 4G Wingle E8372 dongles attached.

When I check their MAC address using `ifconfig` it appears they both have the same MAC address.

I have assigned each dongle a static IP:

```
eth1 - 192.168.100.100
eth2 - 192.168.200.100
```

The problem I am having is sometimes after a reboot it appears that their IPs have switched:

```
eth1 - 192.168.200.100
eth2 - 192.168.100.100
```

Because of the nature of my setup this stops internet from working on each dongle.

Is there any way I can assign the IP address by the USB port in the Raspberry Pi so I can be sure each dongle has the same IP each time?

Comment: What tool / what file are you currently using to configure the IP addresses? (I'm guessing ifupdown via /etc/network/interfaces?)

Comment: I'm editing /etc/dhcpcd.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have managed to solve this by creating `/etc/systemd/network/01-huawei-e8372.link`:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Driver=cdc_ether

[Link]
Description=Huawei E3872
NamePolicy=path
MACAddressPolicy=random
```

What this does is generate a random mac address for each matching device under `[Match]` and then it will name the interface based on the udev path.

So if I plug the dongle into `usb-1.1` it will name the interface `enp1s0u1u1`. If I plug the second device into `usb-1.2` port it will name the interface `enp1s0u1u2`.

I can check the path that the device is plugged into by running `dmesg -w` and re-plugging in the device.

Comment: Excellent idea !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a confusion. eth1 and eth2 are interface names, not MAC. 192.168.200.100 and 192.168.100.100 are Internet addresses.

I ignore what the HUAWEI 4G Wingle E8372 dongles are. Please enter

> lsusb -v

to see details about these devices on USB. The assignment of the IP addresses occurs here at the hotplug level. Then enter

> nmcli device show

and have a look on  GENERAL.HWADDR. This can be the base on which one you can configure each dongle using the NetworkManager.

Comment: Please re-read my question. I stated that the dongles have duplicate MAC addresses. I have assigned eth1 and eth2 static IPs